# How do I detect a chromecast device in Javascript

Tags: google-cast

The app I'm writing will behave differently if it detects that its host is not a chromecast device. What javascript code would determine whether or not it is running on a chromecast device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inspecting the user agent of the browser; search for CrKey" and "TV" and if you get a match for both of them, most likely it is a Chromecast device.

Comment: As of 12 Feb 2014, the Chromecast userAgent no longer contains "TV". Mine is "Mozilla/5.0 (CrKey armv7l 1.4.15250) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.0 Safari/537.36".

Comment: Well, that's a lie. It's 2023, and they still contain `AndroidTV` lol

Answer (score 12):

Currently, you can check for presence of "CrKey" in the user agent of the browser. I have opened [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=157) through Google's issue tracker regarding this. I would suggest you star that issue to be notified of Google's response.

EDIT: Google's response: "Currently that is the way to do it."